# Limits with use of summation

Tags: sequences-and-series

What should i do at first?

$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}+\frac{1}{(n+2)^2}+ \ldots +\frac{1}{(2n)^2}$
i am completely lost in this question more detailed explanation appreciated

Answer (score 4):

Your sum is bounded between $n\cdot\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$ and $n\cdot\frac{1}{(2n)^2}$, hence the limit is zero by squeezing.

Answer (score 2):

There are $n$ terms, each of which is positive and less than or equal to ${1\over (n+1)^2}$

Then

$$0\le\lim_{n\to\infty} {1\over (n+1)^2}+\ldots +{1\over (2n)^2}\le \lim_{n\to\infty} {n\over (n+1)^2}=0$$

Comment: thanks, what about the case in which we would substitute for 1 the variable n? i.e. $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{n}{(n+1)^2}+\frac{n}{(n+2)^2}+ \ldots +\frac{n}{(2n)^2}$

Comment: @kamakrowski34 What do you mean "1 for the variable, n?"

Comment: @kamakrowski34 Oh, I think I see what you were trying to say. That's a separate question, if you want to talk about that, you should post a new one and link to this one explaining how you're interested in the difference between the two.